# Expected score on an exam

Tags: probability

You are taking a 30 question multiple choice test (5 choices per question). The directions say that your grade will equal the number of correct answers minus one fourth of the number of incorrect answers. You are sure you have 20 questions correct. On each of the remaining 10 questions you can definitely eliminate two of the choices. If you choose from the remaining three responses at random what is your expected grade?

On each of the 10 questions you have $.333$ probability of selecting the correct answer. This is pathetic but beyond that I need help.

Answer (score -1):

The expected number of correct answers is $20 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 10$ (you have a $\frac13$ chance in the last $10$) and the expected number of wrong ones is $\frac{2}{3} \cdot 10$. By linearity of expectations, the expected total score is

$$20 + \frac{10}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{20}{3} = 21\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?